# How to evaluate XSLT expression and skip node by condition?

Tags: xslt, saxon

How can I add evaluation on a xslt property, and skip a `for-each` node by condition of that evaluation?

```
<some>
    <deep>
        <level availability="10" code="A"/>
    </deep>
</some>


<xsl:template match="some">
    <xsl:for-each select="//deep//level">
        <xsl:value-of select=".//@code, .//@availability" separator=";"/>
    <xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Question: how can I skip if `availability < 5`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than thinking about "skipping" elements, think about what you want to select, and then put a condition for this in square brackets after the nodes you select

Try this template....

```
<xsl:template match="some">
    <xsl:for-each select="deep/level[number(@availability) ge 5]">
        <xsl:value-of select="@code, @availability" separator=";"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that `//` will search all descendant nodes, not just the immediate child node, which I am not sure you need here.